# Div is growing in length. I want a overflow scroll bar instead - but it is ignored

Tags: css, html, overflow, css-position

I have a div that has the following class:

```
.messages_box {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    height: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
    min-height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* 10px 10px 10px ;*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: #B0E0E6; /*powder blue */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* try so get it not to grow */
    display: table-cell;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

as a child element of a parent modal dialog:

```
        .modal-dialog {
    background: #c1d9ff;
    border: 1px solid #3a5774;
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

In other words, the messages_box sits inside the modal window.
When I add new divs (messages) dynamically in code, the div "messages_box" grows in length.  I never see the overflow scroll bar.  I need the div to be fixed to only 20% of the screen as I mark the height in the CSS.  The page runs on mobile devices and desktops so I would rather not use pixels.

Any ideas?  I have been working this for too many hours to think straight any more.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: `height: 20%; max-height: 20%; min-height: 20%;` Figured you cover all the height bases didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the height of a `div` as a percentage, the container of the `div` needs to have an explicit height on it.
Take a look at my example: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/c9mmG/2/).

```
.message_wrap {
    height:500px;
}
.message_box {
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #B0E0E6;
    padding: 10px;
    width:350px;
    height:20%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="message_wrap">
    <div class="message_box">
        <p class="message">Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI.</p>
        <p class="message">Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service..</p>
        <p class="message">Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

An alternate solution would be change the `max-height` to `vh` units. That is [`viewport-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

<del>`height:20%;`</del> would be `height:20vh;` It would effectively set `.message_box` to 20% of the viewport height, thus no longer needing an explicit height set on the parent.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The vh worked like a charm!  Your expertise is amazing.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!  You are appreciated!